# How do I boot Windows 8 into Safe Mode?

Tags: boot, windows-8, safe-mode

I have Windows 8 Enterprise x64. It's installed a virtual machine. After trying to update VMWare's guest extension it black screened. After resetting it, now the virtual machine won't boot. It just says "automatic repair couldn't repair your PC"

Everything I do ends with an error or it coming back to this screen. If I go to Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Start up settings and then go to Safe Mode, all it will do is say "preparing automatic repair" and then "diagnosing your PC" and then will come straight back to the "automatic repair couldn't repair your PC" screen. It's as if it doesn't even attempt to go into safe made.

Is there anything else I can do before I reformat?

Comment: It sounds like you have tried all the normal supported methods.  If Windows Repair Console is unable to repair the problem you are literaly out of options.

Comment: Yea, even doing a "reset PC" which sounds like a reformat won't work, nor will attempting an upgrade using the Windows 8 disk. Time to reformat I suppose

Comment: Add Safe Mode to the initial Boot menu, it shortens the process a bit, this link is for W7 but I just tried it on W8 and works...http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/212392-safe-mode-add-windows-boot-manager-screen-windows-7-a.html

Comment: Well, since no one else has a suggestion that works, I'd say (depending on how you obtained this ISO...) to check the SHA 1 hash of the ISO to see if it is corrupted in some way - if it doesn't match up, redownload. I am sure you will be able to find the hash somewhere online.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Things are a little bit different in Windows 8. Have a look at the [HowToGeek guide for this](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/) which explains in detail what you may be trying to achieve.

In summary:

1. Mash <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> like you would with F8
2. Click *See advanced repair options*
3. Choose *Troubleshoot*
4. Choose *Advanced options*
5. Choose *Windows Startup Settings*
6. Click *Restart*

[image: Windows 8 Safe Mode]

Comment: When I go to safe mode it just reboots and says "preparing automatic repair"

Comment: Then select disable automatic restart from this menu

Comment: @Luke I should've, but I didn't have too much stuff on it, so I figure faster to just reinstall than try to repair it now.

Comment: @Earlz then try to repair it through the installation disk.

Comment: @avirk tried. Just says "there was an error repairing the installation" or something to that effect.

Comment: @Earlz then I don't think there is something else you have to do with this setup. The all solution is seem for me to a new installation.

Comment: OMG going from F8 to a 6 step process to get safe mode! "The Easy Way" this is a joke right?

Comment: @Moab well you know Microsoft "If it's not broken, change it for the hell of it"

Comment: @Moab - Lets not make a moutain over nothing shall we.  The steps Jay outlined are the exact same steps that you do for Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound what are you smoking, it is not the same thing, try it on your Windows 8 PC its a 7 step process including and extra restart of the PC, Absolutely nothing like W7

Comment: I have a feeling it's an early boot driver issue is why it ends up in this infinite loop. However, this apparently affects both VirtualBox and VMWare. If the machine will properly boot, then getting to safe mode works by this method

Comment: The other answer came here through an exact duplicate question, which was merged into this one. I would say it's fine to stay as-is for the moment.

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft actually has changed the <kbd>F8</kbd> hotkey to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> but didn't mention it.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/):

> The trick is to hold the Shift button and mash the F8 key, this will
>   sometimes boot you into the new advanced "recovery mode",  where you
>   can choose to see advanced repair options.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Shift + F8** does not work....**never** !!!

I recently figured out a way to restart the computer in safe mode without using **msconfig** and **charms bar**. Here is how to do it.

1. When you are at login screen hold the shift key
2. Click on shutdown option available at right bottom corner and click on restart
3. Now windows 8 should start to its usual advanced menu, where you can chose **startup options** to go to safe mode and other diagnostic modes or troubleshoot to go to Recovery Environment.

Try this it works !

Comment: This worked for me. I've tried SHIFT+F8 dozens of times and it wasn't working at all! Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm surprised other people aren't seeing this issue too. Shift + F8 never, ever works for me either. I can't help but wonder why - it could be a lot of things but off the top of my head...maybe our keyboards are unresponsive during this part of boot time or Windows is corrupted...

Comment: Probably the retarded FN (Function) key where some manufacturers make ALT+F4 do nothing so you have to press ALT+FN+F4 to make it close a program...you can *usually* fix it back to the normal function keys in the bios.

Answer (score 2):

Run Command prompt as Admin and type (copy/paste the following line):

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you have safe mode as usual from the boot screen.

To revert:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard
```

Comment: Since I had never heard of `bcdedit` before, I'm going to include the reference to it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I tried this in Windows 8.1 but it does not work. I need to change the safe-mode booting in command line... Is there any other option?