# Can I enter in Safe Mode on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, safe-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I boot Windows 8 into Safe Mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/476187/how-do-i-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode)

I need to enter in safe mode on Windows 8 and I want to know how to do this.

I tried <kbd>F8</kbd> but it didn't work.

Then, I have searched the internet and found this answer: Shift + <kbd>F8</kbd>, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a same problem and find the simple solution in: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zxue/windows-8-how-to-20-how-to-start-windows-8-in-safe-mode)

Is simple (this images is for Developer Preview but works too with other versions):

**1-** Run as Administrator the Command Prompt (in the Start, find Command Prompt and select this option)

**2-** Now enter the BCDEdit command as shown in the screenshot below. `bcdedit /enum /v`

![BCDEdit command][1]

**3-** The command shows you numerous attributes and settings for both Windows Boot Manager and Windows Boot Loader. From Windows Boot Loader section, note down the identifier and description text strings on a text editor. Now enter the following command, as shown in screenshot below.

`bcdedit / copy {identifier} /d “ (Safe Mode)”`

![Command to enter][2]

**4-** Once the entry is successfully copied, open charms bar using Windows+C hotkey combination and use Start Search to open msconfig.exe, or just move to Start Screen and start typing msconfig.exe to search it from Apps category. Now, press Enter to open System Configuration utility.

**5-** Navigate to Boot tab, make sure that Safe Mode is selected, enable Safe boot and underneath Timeout, enable Make all boot settings permanent option. Click OK followed by Restart to reboot your system.

![enter image description here][3]

**6-** Before Windows starts loading, press F8 key to enter into Advanced Boot Options menu. Clicking Safe Mode will prepare your system to load into Safe Mode. After a reboot, it will take you directly to Safe Mode main screen.

I hope you find it useful.