# Hotkey to Boot into Safe Mode in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, safe-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I boot Windows 8 into Safe Mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/476187/how-do-i-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode)

Windows 8 contains a special bootloader which doesn't recognize the <kbd>F8</kbd> hotkey according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/22/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before.aspx) and [this](http://www.techspot.com/news/48718-windows-8-removes-need-for-f8-key-advanced-boot-menu-redesigned.html):

> On Microsoft's MSDN blog, the company has revealed in great detail some of the changes we can expect to see to boot options inherent in Windows 8. Most notably, gone are the days of tapping F8 repeatedly.

So, how do we access safe mode now?