# Two Windows 8 Cursor Arrows, Only one mouse?

Tags: windows-8, cursor

I was using Windows 8 the other day and noticed that there is now a second cursor image (arrow) at the top left of my screen. It doesn't move, it doesn't do anything really, except sometimes go busy if the window below it is loading something.

My regular mouse cursor works as it should and moves when I move my mouse. I checked device manager, but it doesn't think that there's another mouse attached to the computer. It stayed after I rebooted my machine.

What should I do? Should I leave it there and see if it grows? Feed it cheese? Perhaps wiggle the other mouse and see if I can scare it away?

Comment: It's spring, they are multiplying =)

Comment: But srsly, have you recently changed hardware/software configuration of your computer?

Comment: I recently added a new display driver, but i've already uninstalled that :/

Comment: Are there any "unknown devices" in the Device Manager? Does the extra mouse pointer goes away when you restart your PC with your mouse unplugged?

Comment: I've checked for unknown or non-functioning devices, but there doesn't seem to be any. Only one device shows up under the mice header. I haven't tried rebooting without a mouse, but I can try that.

Comment: Does it show up in [safe mode](http://superuser.com/questions/476187/how-do-i-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode)? How about regular mode as a different user?

Comment: It could be an application that shows you another cursor. Windows (usually) displays only one cursor even if two mice are attached: each mouse moves the same, and only, cursor on the screen. Check the process list with Task Manager, there could be a new process that wasn't there before.

Comment: I've also had this issue before and I think rebooting fixed it.  It happened again today in Windows 8.1, which brought me to this question.  The second cursor, which never moves, remains on top regardless of what other windows are open.  I don't recall installing any new software lately, and I'm sure if the NSA had installed something they would have called me first.

Answer (score 1):

I was making changes on Windows screen resolution option and i noticed that i had more than 1 screen activated (extend desktop). I enabled only one, and after that the left screen mouse clone disappeared.