# restart loop in my windows 8 after manipulating msconfig

Tags: windows-8, command-line, msconfig

My 64bit windows 8was working ok untill  changed msconfig boot mode to safe(my hp driver wont install). After restarting my system, windows starts to boot but suddenly a blue screen shows up and vanishes so fast and resets my system in a loop.

I dont have access to safe mode becose f8 is disabled in win8 to change msconfig to normal boot.

I dont have any reg or system restore backups
Is there any way I can set msconfig boot mode to normal from my win8 installation disk command prompt?

**Edit** blue screen says this error: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Comment: As it seems, if normal boot fails in windows 8, your chances are low to go to safemode. Its meaningless. I go to safemode becose normal boot is failed but win 8 wont allow safemode until normal boot succeeds!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I boot Windows 8 into Safe Mode?](http://superuser.com/questions/476187/how-do-i-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode)

Comment: @techie007 the problem is not just booting to safe mode becose it wont boot to safemore too.i need a command prompt command to revert msconfig settings

Comment: The instructions in the accepted answer show how to access the "old style" boot menu, which includes Command Prompt options.