# Removing a virus from Win 8 -- safe mode?

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to remove a virus from a relative's win 8 machine.

As is very common with malware, while it's running, it will thwart any attempt to install antivirus if anti malware.

I usually get around this by booting into safe mode. However, I gather that MS chose to do away with the F8 boot option, and when I try to use the "advanced boot options" screen to configure safe mode, the malware closes the screens.

It also closes command prompt windows.

So what do I need to do to get into safe mode?

Comment: Answered over here in SuperUser.


  http://superuser.com/questions/476187/how-do-i-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the msconfig utility and click on the boot tab you will see options to boot into safe mode.

On another note, when I'm having problems launching AV software because of an infection I download a copy of Rkill on another computer, transfer to USB and run it on the infected computer. For some reason Rkill always manages to launch and never fails to kill any malware process on the system.

I don't like scanning in safe mode because a lot of malware hooks into drivers which aren't loaded in safe mode.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/